# Crash when C++ program calls Delphi DLL function

Tags: c++, delphi, function, dll, crash

I have an abstract class in a C++ program that looks like

```
class Interface {
    virtual void blah() = 0;
    virtual int  asdf() = 0;
};
```

and that C++ program allows you to load DLLs with LoadLibrary. When you load a DLL, it calls a function in the DLL called Setup with GetProcAddress, passing a pointer to a subclass of Interface as a parameter.

I have a Delphi DLL mimics that class and exposes the Setup function like this:

```
type 
Interface = class abstract
    procedure blah(); virtual; abstract;
    function asdf() : Integer; virtual; abstract;
end;

function Setup(I : Interface) : Integer; export; cdecl;
begin
    Result := 0;
end

exports Setup;
```

But when the program calls the function, it crashes. If I change the function Setup to this:

```
function Setup(I : Pointer) : Integer; export; cdecl;
```

It works fine and doesn't crash, but of course I can't just leave it like that, I need to be able to use the class. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know how to solve your problem as I don't use (nor care?) much about calling conventions. But I was going to say that it looks like you are on the right track with modifying your calling convention. You might want to change it for your C++ interface.

Comment: I don't have control over the C++ code, just the delphi.

Comment: You really have absolutely no control over the C++ code? You can't even complain to the C++ developers that they screwed up, and then demand that they fix it? That's not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your C++ code really is as you say it is, you need to determine what calling convention it's using. Is it definitely using the C calling convention? What is it compiled with, and what flags for calling convention?

Your `Interface` class needs to include the calling convention too, something like:

```
Interface = class abstract
  procedure blah(); cdecl; virtual; abstract;
  function asdf() : Integer; cdecl; virtual; abstract;
end;
```

If the calling convention used by C++ is something like MSVC's fastcall, there's no direct equivalent in Delphi. What you could do in that case is write a proxy DLL in MSVC that converts the interface from MSVC fastcall to cdecl or similar.

Comment: No, the calling convention is definitely cdecl. Just to make sure I tried stdcall as well, it crashes too.

Comment: @john how can you really be certain of that? Just because __stdcall crashes too isn't enough to make that determination. Do you have access to the header files to the C++ library you're trying to interface with? I would start by taking a look at and see how it's prototyped. Barry's suggestion of wrapping the interface is probably your best bet.

Comment: Microsoft C++ classes do *not* use *cdecl* as their calling convention. They use *thiscall*. That puts the object pointer in the ECX register and the declared parameters on the stack. With *cdecl*, the pointer will be at the top of the stack, which is where Delphi is looking for it. Use explicitly declared calling conventions on *both* classes.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I don't know about C++, but Delphi interfaces are automatically reference counted (via IUnknown). Looks like your interface has been destroyed already by the time you try to use it.</strike>

Edit:
Sorry, I was confused: you're not using interfaces.

Delphi and C++ classes aren't compatible, so I don't think this is going to work. You'd have to change the class to a COM interface or a record of function pointers. If you don't have control over the C++ side you're out of luck I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You could see http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html

But yes, using C++ in Delphi is not an easy thing... and not suitable.